# setSource not taken into account by Cakephp tree behavior

Tags: cakephp, croogo

Tree behavior and associations is working well in my application.

I'm trying to switch tree table on runtime, which works well with following code in beforeFind method:

```
$this->setSource($table);
```

However, when I'm reordoning the tree using the recover method, the table name is not taken into account for all queries: I'm getting SHOW COLUMN queries on the new table, and SELECT queries on the default one. I tried to disable and clear cache of my application without success.

I'm also changing the table of associated Models, but problem arrises without it too.

Any piece of advice will be appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the model used:
https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/1.3/models/taxonomy.php

I disabled (permanently, not at runtime) the Cache behavior.

I traced the problem into recover method, the bindModel does not take into account the useTable.

```
 $Model->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('VerifyParent' => array(
                            'className' => $Model->name,
                            'foreignKey' => $parent,
                            'fields' => array($Model->primaryKey, $left, $right, $parent),
                    ))));
```

I tried without success:

```
$Model->VerifyParent->useTable = $Model->useTable;
```

I opened a lighthouse ticket:
https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3820-cannot-change-table-name-using-treebehaviorrecover-in-shell

```
belongsTo associations cannot define custom tables for the linked model. You may need to seed ClassRegistry with a properly configured model with the VerifyParent key.
```

Comment: If I debug into recover method of the Tree behavior, the useTable is properly set.

Comment: Cakephp version is 1.3.14

Comment: Hi @snowflake, can you provide us with some insight into why you need to declare this behavior at run-time? Also, would you post your model's code in your question. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam Delaney, the tree behavior is not declared at runtime. The "table change behavior" is at run time cause I'm using Croogo that store all "taxonomies" in a single table. I have many different data that I'd like to easy manipulate (load/unload), and several tables is the more appropriate.

Comment: PHP version is PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli).

Comment: It works well on windows with PHP 5.3.5 (cli)

Comment: have you tried debugging the `recover()` method? Seems peculiar why the version of PHP or the platform should make a difference.

Comment: My bad, it does not works well on windows, I debugged the recover method and one query is performed on the wrong table (not using setSource):  LEFT JOIN `taxonomies` AS `VerifyParent`. I thought it was because the taxonomies table was filled with appropriate data.

Comment: So just to be clear, any queries generated by calling the `recover()` method do not take into consideration the changes made to `useTable`. May I suggest you detach (`$Model->Behaviors->unload('Tree')`) and then re-attach (`$Model->Behaviors->enable('Tree')`) the `tree` behavior prior to calling `recover()`

Comment: Absolutely. Re-attaching has no effect.  I opended a ticket on Cakephp Lighthouse and updated my question with new details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be fixed by modifying the Tree behavior:

```
$Model->VerifyParent->setSource($Model->useTable)
```

This a bug accepted and referenced here:
https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3820-cannot-change-table-name-using-treebehaviorrecover-in-shell

However, not sure it will be fixed in cakephp source as it is very specific.

Comment: The Cake project has since switched its bug tracking to Github Issues, so the link above no longer works. This approach also does **not** work with Cake 2.5 (at least). Additionally, a dynamically created Model (using `new Model()`) that also utilizes TreeBehavior not only can not set a different source table, but also can not use a dataSource (as defined in `Config/database.php`) other than the default. The source issue in both cases seem to be the `bindModel()` @snowflake originally identified in the question.